# Cannot upload file type image on Yii

Tags: yii

I has been successfully uploaded an image, but the file type of image is not uploaded. As Example 123.jpg, on the store folder of upload is only 123 (unknown file type).

Here is my code :

```
    const URLX ="/../foto/";
    public function actionCreate()

{

    $model=new TbBatik;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['TbBatik']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['TbBatik'];
        $simpanSementara=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'Foto');
        if($model->save())
        {

             $simpanSementara->saveAs(yii::app()->basePath.self::URLX.$model->id_batik.'');

            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id_batik));
        }
        }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
    }
```

**How to upload a file with originally file type with Yii?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a little change in your code:

```
    $extension = $simpanSementara->getExtensionName();
    $simpanSementara->saveAs(yii::app()->basePath.self::URLX.$model->id_batik.'.'.$extension);
```